# How do I detect that a user has gone through the 'Forgot Password' workflow in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently using the action hook `profile_update` to execute some code whenever the user updates his/her profile, but this action is not called when the user goes through the 'forgot password' workflow (click forgot password -> send email -> click link in email -> change password) to change their password.

I've read through the [list of available actions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) and nothing seems appropriate. Note, I need to execute code *after* they've changed their password.

Answer (score 0):

change the link of the "forget password" to a PHP that you'll write and which will log all the details (user-id, time, etc), and then your PHP script can redirect the customer to the original URL using header() method.

Comment: What I need to do though is run some code after the user has entered in a new password.

Comment: You didn't understand my answer...
you create a "change_pwd.php" file and submit the form to this php.
There you change the user's pwd and do all the logic that you want.
after you're done - you can redirect the user to any page you want.